# Raised Error when I run python manage.py in Django in linux vps

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, vps

I've recently cloned my django project into a linux vps. I used python3.10 in my system but in vps I have python3.8 . Actually I installed all necessary packages for it and also created database. I have this error whenever I run commands start with `python manage.py`. Can any body help me to solve it? Maybe this error is for different python version?

It also raised the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'` but I have no idea where I defined 'mysite' module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Comment: It's not a python version error. It's likely to do with your path settings. Is `mysite` your project or an app within the project though? Could be it's missing from `INSTALLED_APPS`. Probably the path though if it's working locally.

Comment: No it is not my project or my project's name. I've not created any app in my django project with this name.

Comment: OK, well that's odd, becuase nothing in DJango is called that. Have you searched your codebase for this? Something is looking for `mysite` ...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made a mistake when I defined a variable for Django setting module in linux bash. Thank you for your comments.